# Documentation for XHTML Attributes in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

good afternoon,

switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ i'm wondering, is there any XHTML attribute tooltip for documentation in IntelliJ? In Eclipse (honestly, with the JBoss Tools) you see the documentation for that. For example, if i hover over "value" in `<h:inputText value="">` i see a tooltip coming up. Is this possible in IntelliJ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the cursor over the value and hit.<kbd>Control</kbd> - <kbd>J</kbd>. If there is documentation, then it'll display in a dialog. That also works for Javadoc, as well.

Edit: It's <kbd>Control</kbd> - <kbd>J</kbd> on OSX. This activates the Quick Documentation feature under the View menu. According to [this page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/viewing-inline-documentation.html), it's <kbd>Control</kbd> - <kbd>Q</kbd> on other platforms.

Comment: CTRL + J ...according to the Default Keymap this shortcut insert a Live Template?

Comment: I'm using Mac, so I think the keystroke must be different. Control-J brings up Quick Documentation (under the View menu).

Answer (score 0):

dbrown lead me the way. in my case strg + q will do the trick.